# Neo4j Spatial - how to specify a start node for withindistance

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I was able to successfully install Neo4j and Neo4j Spatial and run the query:

```
START n=node:geom('withinDistance:[51.521348,-0.128113, 10.0]') RETURN node;
```

I am probably missing something fundamental, but is there a way for me to set a starting node for Node4j Spatial to start calculating 'withinDistance'?

For example, I would like to run node:geom('withinDistance:[51.521348,-0.128113, 10.0]') starting on node(5000), for example.

Thanks.

Comment: I think right now you have to compute that lat, lon externally and pass it in as a query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would have to find the Lon/Lat of your starting node. What does "starting" mean? What is your domain setup?

/peter